# how to inject componenet in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using meanjs(meanjs.org) boiler plate code to build my website and I want to implement file upload feature in the website.

I am using https://github.com/ghostbar/angular-file-model and installed the component and added into bower.json. How do I inject it into my application

Following is the usage written on the website

Install with bower:

```
bower install angular-file-model --save
```

Add to your HTML files:

```
<script src='/bower_components/angular-file-model/angular-file-model.js'></script>
```

Now, inject to your application:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['file-model']);
```

How do I inject in my app?

```
angular.module('articles').controller('ArticlesController', ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$location', 'Authentication', 'Articles',
    function($scope, $stateParams, $location, Authentication, Articles) {
        $scope.authentication = Authentication;

        $scope.file = null;

        $scope.$watch('file', function (newVal) {
            if (newVal)             console.log(newVal);
        });

        $scope.create = function() {
            var article = new Articles({
                title: this.title,
                content: this.content
            });
            article.$save(function(response) {
                $location.path('articles/' + response._id);

                $scope.title = '';
                $scope.content = '';
            }, function(errorResponse) {
                $scope.error = errorResponse.data.message;
            });
        };

        $scope.remove = function(article) {
            if (article) {
                article.$remove();

                for (var i in $scope.articles) {
                    if ($scope.articles[i] === article) {
                        $scope.articles.splice(i, 1);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                $scope.article.$remove(function() {
                    $location.path('articles');
                });
            }
        };

        $scope.update = function() {
            var article = $scope.article;

            article.$update(function() {
                $location.path('articles/' + article._id);
            }, function(errorResponse) {
                $scope.error = errorResponse.data.message;
            });
        };

        $scope.find = function() {
            $scope.articles = Articles.query();
        };

        $scope.findOne = function() {
            $scope.article = Articles.get({
                articleId: $stateParams.articleId
            });
        };
    }
]);
```

is my controller page. Which can be found at https://github.com/meanjs/mean

my view page is

```
<section data-ng-controller="ArticlesController" data-ng-init="find()">
    <div class="page-header">
        <h1>Articles</h1>
    </div>
    <form>
        <input type='file' file-model='file'>
    </form>

</section>
```

Comment: nice profile, and nice joke ;)

Comment: What is `articles` module definition?

Comment: added whole controller file

Comment: I mean where do you declare `articles` module? like `angular.module('articles', [])`?

Comment: use the`file-model` directive like in their example : http://plnkr.co/edit/0ZHCsR?p=preview - just add this in your html `<input type='file' file-model='file'>` and $watch file in $scope.

Comment: I added watch but still when I upload it still doesnt print anything.

Comment: You should have a line that looks like `angular.module('articles', [...]);` in your app where [...] might be empty or be an array of strings. Show us that line. Or put `'file-model'` in the array.